# react dom manipulation issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

any tip on how to convert this js code to react...

```
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
  if (!active) return;
  let x = e.pageX;
  x -= document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  scrollMove(x);
  console.log("moving")
  
});


function scrollMove(x){
  let transform = Math.max(0,(Math.min(x,document.querySelector('.container').offsetWidth)));
  if (active==="container-mid"){
    document.querySelector('.container-mid').style.width = transform+"px";
    scrolMid.style.left = transform-25+"px";
    if (scrolTip.getBoundingClientRect().left>scrolMid.getBoundingClientRect().left-5){
      document.querySelector('.mainTop').style.width = transform-5+"px";
      scrolTip.style.left = transform-30+"px";
    }
  }}
return (

<div className="container">
  <div className="container-mid">...</div>
    <div className=scrolMid>......</div>
    <div className="maintip">
    <div className=scrolMid>......</div>
  </div>
)
```

**however, i tried converting the above code like this using the neccessary react hooks which are useRef, react event handler. but the later function which is the scrollmove failed to triggered when the onMouseMove event was called as seen in the code below**

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);
const ytu = () => {
   if (!active) return;
  let x = e.pageX;
  x -= document.containerRef.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  scrollMove(x);
  console.log("moving")
}

return (
<div className="container"
ref={containerRef}
onMouseMove={ytu}
>
)
```

**and, the rest like this**

```
const container-midRef = useRef(null);
const scrolMidRef-midRef = useRef(null);
const scrolTipRef = useRef(null);
const mainTopRef = useRef(null);


function scrollMove(x){
  let transform = Math.max(0,(Math.min(x,document.containerRef.offsetWidth)));
  if (active==="container-midRef"){
    document.container-midRef.style.width = transform+"px";
    scrolMidRef.style.left = transform-25+"px";
    if (scrolTipRef.getBoundingClientRect().left>scrolMidRef.getBoundingClientRect().left-5){
      document.mainTopRef.style.width = transform-5+"px";
      scrolTipRef.style.left = transform-30+"px";
    }
  }}
```

The scrollMove(x) function is not triggered. maybe there is a mistake on my part.

Comment: any tips guys will be appreciated.